SOAP WSDL to OpenAPI Swagger
Anyone tried to convert WSDL into OpenAPI format, Swagger?
Previously I tried to use https://github.com/wso2/soap-to-rest to convert and managed to do it. But as my requirements get complex, I am not sure what should be the display for much complex WSDL format. Is there any tools that can use to load the WSDL and display the OpenAPI format?
I am looking for advise.
